# how to parse a single apache log entry into a python object

Tags: python, apache, parsing, object, logging

I'm sitting over my first python script trying to parse an apache log into an accessible object and I can't get it work.

I'm trying to use [this](http://css.dzone.com/articles/apache-log-parsing-python) example (running `Python 2.7`) and just want to get it to work with a single log entry.

Here is what I have:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

format_pat= re.compile( 
    r"(?P<host>[\d\.]+)\s" 
    r"(?P<identity>\S*)\s" 
    r"(?P<user>\S*)\s"
    r"\[(?P<time>.*?)\]\s"
    r'"(?P<request>.*?)"\s'
    r"(?P<status>\d+)\s"
    r"(?P<bytes>\S*)\s"
    r'"(?P<referer>.*?)"\s'
    r'"(?P<user_agent>.*?)"\s*' 
)

Access = namedtuple('Access',
    ['host', 'identity', 'user', 'time', 'request',
    'status', 'bytes', 'referer', 'user_agent'] )

# my entry
log = '2001:470:1f14:169:15f3:824f:8a61:7b59 - ABC-15414 [14/Nov/2012:09:32:31 +0100] "POST /setConnectionXml HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "-" 102356'

match= format_pat.match(log) 
print match

if match:
   Access( **match.groupdict() )
   print Access
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but `match` returns `none`, instead of the object I was hoping for.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `host` entry matches only digits and dots (IPv4 addresses), but the log entry example you posted is an IPv6 address. Adjust your pattern to allow for that format too (so either match digits and dots, or match hex characters and colons:

```
format_pat= re.compile( 
    r"(?P<host>(?:[\d\.]|[\da-fA-F:])+)\s" 
    r"(?P<identity>\S*)\s" 
    r"(?P<user>\S*)\s"
    r"\[(?P<time>.*?)\]\s"
    r'"(?P<request>.*?)"\s'
    r"(?P<status>\d+)\s"
    r"(?P<bytes>\S*)\s"
    r'"(?P<referer>.*?)"\s'
    r'"(?P<user_agent>.*?)"\s*' 
)
```

With that adjustment, your example matches:

```
>>> format_pat.match(log).groupdict()
{'status': '200', 'bytes': '4', 'request': 'POST /setConnectionXml HTTP/1.1', 'host': '2001:470:1f14:169:15f3:824f:8a61:7b59', 'referer': '-', 'user': 'ABC-15414', 'time': '14/Nov/2012:09:32:31 +0100', 'identity': '-', 'user_agent': '-'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `format_pat.search(log)`

```
In [6]: m = format_pat.search(log)

In [7]: m.groupdict()
Out[7]: 
{'bytes': '4',
 'host': '59',
 'identity': '-',
 'referer': '-',
 'request': 'POST /setConnectionXml HTTP/1.1',
 'status': '200',
 'time': '14/Nov/2012:09:32:31 +0100',
 'user': 'ABC-15414',
 'user_agent': '-'}
```

Comment: Check @MartijnPieters answer, mine does not take into account the problem with the regex.

Comment: Remember that `re.match` matches from the beginning of the string and returns `None` if the first regex fails. `re.search` will go through the entire string and return matches. Check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) for more info, this might still be relevant for you.